# HTML to A4 page for print, 8 rows per page

Tags: html, css

I have a method that gets data from a MySql database and then puts it in a table. This works fine, but what I want to do is to print the table with 3 cols and 8 rows per A4 page (For label printing).

Any thoughts on how I might accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A4 sticker label right? I still using it for my local business.

[image]

1.add this style for A4 page

```
@page {
  size: A4;
  margin: 0;
}
```

2. add this style class to your table

```
.address_label {
    page-break-after: always;
}
```

3. fix width = 274px , height = 141px in each column

4 you might need to swap column by using sorting script like this https://github.com/james2doyle/zepto-dragswap

5.you might need to edit label by using jeditor script https://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable

Good luck.